# JQuery BlockUI stay alive

Tags: jquery, blockui

I have a webpage that submits a request to the server. I'm using blockUI to block the page until the server completes it's task. When that task takes too long, the web page will show "This page can’t be displayed" How can I keep the page alive until the server completes?

I have the following code attached to the button on the page that submits the request to the server:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {              
            $('a.button').click(function() {                    
                $.blockUI({ 
                    message: '<h2>Please wait while the repository is being updated...</h2>',
                    css: 
                    {   
                        border: 'none',            
                        padding: '15px',             
                        backgroundColor: '#000',             
                        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',             
                        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',             
                        opacity: .6,            
                        color: '#fff'         
                    } 
                });                      
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is yout request in your js?

Comment: We would need to see the request, the code you have provided has nothing to do with your page timing out.